Displaying images from static folder in Django
We have a problem with displaying images on html pages. We create graph, save it and then pass it's url to html page via context, but django can't find the picture (Error 404 Not Found). There's no model to store urls as there's no need to access them later.
Here's our views.py:
def simple_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['file']:
        myfile = request.FILES['file']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        
        # this is the function that returns image url
        forecast, clean_df, graph_url = data_processing(myfile, filename)

        forecast = forecast.reset_index()
        cols_fc = forecast.columns.tolist()
        forecast[cols_fc[0]] = forecast[cols_fc[0]].dt.date
        forecast = forecast.values.tolist()

        clean_df = clean_df.reset_index()
        cols_df = clean_df.columns.tolist()
        clean_df[cols_df[0]] = clean_df[cols_df[0]].dt.date
        clean_df = clean_df.values.tolist()

        context = {
            'filename': filename,
            'cols_fc': cols_fc,
            'forecast': forecast,
            'cols_df': cols_df,
            'clean_df': clean_df,
            'graph_url': graph_url,
        }
        return render(request, 'project/results.html', context)
    return render(request,'project/example.html')

Function data_processing():
def data_processing(filename):
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)
    cols = df.columns.values.tolist()
    df = df.set_index(cols[0])
    df = df[[cols[1]]]
    
    clean_df = process_missing(df)
    integr = stationate_data(clean_df)
    
    model_param = search_optimal_arima(clean_df, integr)
    model = sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA(clean_df, order=model_param, freq='MS')
    results = model.fit()
    
    forecast = get_forecast(results, clean_df, cols[1])
    graph_url = make_graph(forecast, clean_df, cols, filename)
    return forecast, clean_df, graph_url

Function make_graph():
def make_graph(forecast, df, cols, filename):
    plt.figure(figsize=(16,4))
    plt.plot(df, label="Реальные значения", color="blue")
    plt.plot(forecast, label='Прогноз', color='red')

    plt.title(filename)
    plt.xlabel(cols[1])
    plt.ylabel(cols[0])
    plt.legend()

    figname = (f'{filename}_forecast.png')

    plt.savefig(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'graphs/', figname))

    return figname

Html document result.html:
<body>
{% load static %}
    <p>{{ filename }}</p>
    <p>------------------------------------------------------</p>
    <div>{{ graph_url }}</div>
    <img src="{% static '{{ graph_url }}' %}">
    <p style="color:red"> ------------ VALUES -----------</p>
    <p>{{ cols_df }}</p>
    {% for c in clean_df %}
        <p>{{ c.0 }} || {{ c.1 }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    <p style="color:blue">------------- FORECAST -------------</p>
    <p>{{ cols_fc }}</p>
    {% for f in forecast %}
        <p>{{ f.0 }} || {{ f.1 }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</body>

Static/media urls:
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL)

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, MEDIA_URL)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project/static/static_files/'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media/graphs/')
)

We've tried passing picture different ways:

Writing full url path/to/{{ url }} and with static directory {% static '{{ url }}'%} but these don't work.

We are pretty sure the problem lies in graph_url, because when we pass image name from the same folder manually (typing its name like 'image.png'), it displays fine. Any ideas why that happens?

graph_url is returned from the data_processing() function, but you did not show us that function.

Also the URL ought to be one Django has permission to access on the filesystem.

FileSystemStorage.save() returns the name of the File not its Python Path.

@ChukwujiobiCanon that part saves the other file, not the image we want to display

So that part i.e. data_processing() works flawlessly then?

@ChukwujiobiCanon yes. all data it returns is correct, the only problem is that django can't find saved image when we pass it to src

Hmm that's weird. So <div>{{ graph_url }}</div> and what you manually type are exactly the same value? Hmm.

@ChukwujiobiCanon yes

the static tag only returns the images/files under the static folder, the files you manually place. It seems you are saving them in the media folder and calling the static tag to render the image, as a result django cant find it.
maybe save the file in a model for rendering the images

I understand this, but the image is saved before displaying and we can see it in directory. The route to that folder is in staticfiles_dirs. If I type like "image.png" (it being in the same folder as just saved image) instead of {{ graph_url }}, then image.png shows, so it is not clear to me what exactly is the problem. But we'll think about making a model if there won't be any other solution, thank you

The built-in template tag static takes a path and urljoins it with the static prefix STATIC_URL.

When you have an environment like so:
ROOT URL: http://localhost:8000
STATIC URL: cdn/files
An img tag with the src:
{% static 'images/hi.jpg' %}
Will have its src normalized as follows:
http://localhost:8000/cdn/files/images/hi.jpg
And if the file hi.jpg exists in the folder STATIC_ROOT/images, [1] this file will get fetched by the browser and displayed for you.

If you don’t want this normalization, then don’t use the static tag. [2]
<img src="{{ graph_url }}">

[1] This folder doesn’t have to exist on the filesystem. See STORAGES. [django-docs]
[2] Only do this if you know what you are doing.

I could give you another answer but it will require a redesign of your application.
